# Converting a mesh to voxels

Tags: mesh, export, image, conversion

Is it possible to convert a mesh into a voxel image?

This operation would make white voxels inside the mesh, and black voxels outside the mesh, and would either:

1. write a standard 3D image file format, or just a raw voxel dump; or
2. create a stack of 2D images in each axis

Comment: a script would be the better solution but you can use dynamic paint :  animate a  plane ( the canvas with high dry speed)  to go through the mesh ( the brush ) then bake the image sequence

Comment: I'm fluent in Python but have never made the dive into learning `bpy`. This is just a once off operation for me, so I'd rather not spend the time scripting. I'll see if I can figure out your dynamic paint suggestion.

Comment: I didn't try, but there is [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851342/in-python-how-do-i-voxelize-a-3d-mesh)  (though OP there asked about .obj, but still maybe some general usage)

Comment: @Chebhou the dynamic paint solution worked well. Want me to add it as an answer?

Comment: @ajwood of course, go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Chebhou suggested in the comments, the 2D image stack can be achieved with dynamic painting an animated plane.

1. Add a plane, and animate it to pass through the main mesh
2. In the physics panel of the main mesh, enable Dynamic Paint and make it a brush
3. In the physics panel of the plane, enable Dynamic Paint and make it a canvas with these settings:

   - Format: Image Sequence
   - Dry time: 1
   - Dissolve time: 1
4. In the Dynamic Paint Output panel, click "Bake Image Sequence" to write out the plane/mesh intersection at each frame of the animation.